# How To Read Member Variables of An Array of Structs From a Binary File?

Tags: c, file-io, io, binaryfiles, fread

So my struct looks like this

```
typedef struct file {
    char name[20];
    int size;
    int offset;
} file;
```

This function is supposed to print out the names of the file and size in sorted order. Right now it looks like so:

```
int list(char *archiveFile) {
    FILE *binFile;
    int numFiles;
    file files[MAX];

    binFile = fopen(archiveFile, "rb");
    if (binFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "binary file not opening\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // gets number of files currently 
    fread(&numFiles, sizeof(numFiles), 1, binFile);

    // read contents 
    for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        fread(&files[i].name, sizeof(files[i].name), 1, binFile);
        fread(&files[i].size, sizeof(files[i].size), 1, binFile);
        fread(&files[i].offset, sizeof(files[i].offset), 1, binFile);

        printf("name: %s\n", files[i].name);
        printf("size: %d\n", files[i].size);
        printf("offset: %d\n", files[i].offset);
    }
    fclose(binFile);
    return 0;
}
```

And it's supposed to return

```
name: file1.txt
size: 12
offset: <some_number> (position of file contents relative to the beginning of binary file)
name: file2.txt
size: 10
offset: <some_number>
```

I get gibberish for the name and very huge numbers for size and offset and I believe it's because C has no bound-checking.

For reference, the structure of binary file:

```
number of files --> 4 bytes
array of file structs --> 28 bytes each, 560 bytes for 20 files which is the MAX
contents of each file --> append to the END of the file in order
```

Just for additional information, here's how I created the binary file:

```
int create(char *archiveFile, file list[], int numFiles) {
    FILE *binFile;
     
    binFile = fopen(archiveFile, "wb");
    if (binFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // writing num of files
    fwrite(&numFiles, sizeof(numFiles), 1, binFile);
    // writing structs of information
    fwrite(&list, sizeof(file), numFiles, binFile); 
    fclose(binFile);
    writeContentsToBin(archiveFile, list, numFiles);
    return 0;

}
```

What is the best way I can create or read these file contents so that I'm able to see the file name, correct size, and offset?

Comment: For a text file, you would read/write *each* struct member. For a binary file, you would read/write the *entire* struct, with a single operation.

Comment: When you write the entire array, you're including padding. If you reading it back one item at a time, you don't get the correct padding.

Comment: @WeatherVane So, I can just do a for loop and `fread(&files[i], sizeof(file), 1, binFile)` or grab the entire array of structs in one go like `fread(&files, sizeof(file) * numFiles, 1, binFile)`?

Comment: So you should read it the same way you wrote: `fread(files, sizeof(file), numFiles, binFile);`

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `&files`. Arrays automatically decay to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @Barmar wait wouldn't it be `fread(files, sizeof(file) * numFiles, 1, binFile)` because I'm taking in an array of structs?

Comment: No, the number of array elements should be in the third argument, just like with `fwrite()`.

Comment: No, because you want to read `numFiles` *whole* structs and then check the return value from `fread()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane @Barmar when I do `fread(files, sizeof(file), numFiles, binFile)`, it's return value is 2. For context, I have 2 `file` elements in the files array. Shouldn't it be 56 since `sizeof(file)` is 28 and there are 2 files?

Comment: No, `fread` return the number of items of the given size that were successfully read.

Comment: @WeatherVane when I for loop and print the `files` elements, I get `0: ���   3 45394667
1:  47698848 2`, why are the numbers so large?

Comment: As mentioned, `&list` should be `list`. The `&list` is the location of the function argument, on the stack.

Comment: @WeatherVane I still get the same result regardless

Comment: I suggest you post the updated code, as a new question, as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing how you write and read the file.

Comment: use `#pragma pack(1)`